# Where should bower installed stuff go if you want to call it in an index.html?

Tags: node.js, bower

I am very new to node/js...

I noticed this [demo](http://kartenkarsten.github.io/leaflet-layer-overpass/demo/) and was intrigued enough to try to replicate it following the [git-hub explanation](https://github.com/kartenkarsten/leaflet-layer-overpass).

I followed the

```
bower install --save leaflet-layer-overpass
```

specified in the instructions, and cloned the repo. It appeared successful...and shows up in a 'C:\Users\me\bower_components' folder, but I have no clue what to do with it. Is it suppose to go in a folder along - with the 'dist' & 'src' files the instructions referenced in order for an index.html to be able to reference it?

Any ideas?

Comment: `./bower_components` usually

Comment: my file crawl found it - how does an index.html know about it though? Do I need to move it to a local dir where the index.html is located?

Comment: depends on the file / package in question (especially since a bower package can contain whatever it wants and there isn't *really* an enforced standard layout).  Often the answer is `<script src="bower_components/whatever/src/somescript.js"></script>`

Comment: so adding this line to my index.html ... should work (seeing if I copied the folder from 'bower_components' to 'src'? '<script src=".../src/leaflet-layer-overpass/OverpassLayer.js"></script>'